# Ridge Regression with two estimators

Tags: regression, least-squares, regularization

Given a loss $E$:
$$E = (Y - X\beta)^T(Y - X\beta) + \lambda\left \| \beta \right \|^2$$
The value of $\beta$ that minimizes the loss can be obtained by setting $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \beta} =0$

However I am interested in something like this:

$$E = (Y - X_1\beta - X_2\alpha)^T(Y - X_1\beta - X_2\alpha) + \lambda\left \|\alpha+ \beta \right \|^2$$

Can just solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by setting $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \alpha} =0$ and $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \beta} =0$ so that I get two equations for two variables ? Or there is some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$\gamma = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{pmatrix}$$
and define the matrices
$$\Gamma = \begin{pmatrix}
X_2 \; | \; X_1
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad \Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{I} \; | \; \mathbb{I} \
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix with order equal to the length of $\alpha$ (or $\beta$). Then, you can write your expression as
$$E = (Y - \Gamma\gamma)^\top (Y - \Gamma\gamma) + \lambda ||\Lambda\gamma||^2$$
and find the optimal values of $\gamma$ solving the equation
$$\frac{dE}{d\gamma} = 0.$$

Comment: This is interesting. Can you explain the reason behind zeros in the $\Gamma$ matrix; because the dimensions are not working out. If I define $\Gamma= \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
X_2 & X_1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ then all the dimensions work out.

Comment: Hey @SalilBhat. Yes, my bad. Now I have corrected the expression.

Comment: Another thing, I didnt follow is why $\Lambda$ is defined with two identity matrices concatenated horizontally ? Isnt just one identity matrix sufficient ?

Comment: Take the case that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have just two coordinates. Then, $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \beta_1 \\ \beta_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1 + \beta_1\\ \alpha_2 + \beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\alpha + \beta$$

Comment: Ah but, in my case $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are matrices (not vectors) with same columns but different rows

Comment: When you minimize a loss function like the first $E$ you wrote (which is a ridge regression loss function), $\beta$ is a vector. Why now is a matrix?

Comment: Ah it has always been a matrix in my case. I dont think I mentioned $beta$ as a vector

Comment: You should have mentioned it since it is commonly a vector hahaha. However, you can always transform a matrix to a vector using the vectorization function.